# Confusion over 'ssh' command for networking

Tags: ros, ssh, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

I am trying to create a ROS network between two computers. The computer A as master (userA@ComputerNameA:~$) and computer B as client (userB@ComputerNameB:~$). I also set ROS Environment Variables as follow.

On Computer A:
export ROS_HOSTNAME= ComputerNameA
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://ComputerNameA:11311

On Computer B:
export ROS_HOSTNAME=ComputerNameB
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://ComputerNameA:11311

My problem is when I want to test the network connectivity by SSH command before using ROS packages I get confused and don't know which command I must run on which computer, Master or Client?

For example, If I must run the ssh command on master (computer A), which one of these commands is correct?

1- (userA@ComputerNameA:~$)  ssh userA@ComputerNameB
 or
2- (userA@ComputerNameA:~$)  ssh userB@ComputerNameB

Thanks...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199957/confusion-over-%27ssh%27-command-for-networking/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding the command to run `ssh`, the user must exist on the remote machine, thus your second command is the correct one.

If you'd like to deepen your understanding of how `ssh` works, the top hits of a google search for `ssh tutorial` will come handy.

That said, I would also advise you to export the environment variable `ROS_IP` for each computer. For instance, for computer A: `export ROS_IP=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` (replacing the x's with computer A's IP address).

You may also find the following two links useful:

[ROS/NetworkSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup)

[ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines)

I hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-22**:
Thanks. it works